# YouTube subscriber login relationships

Tags: google-api, gmail-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api, youtube-channels

I want to create a website where a user can login using their google account. Once logged it I want to check if this user is a subscriber of my YouTube channel or a paid member of my channel. Can this me done ?

I want to do this so that I can take this data and split them into two groups for allowing different access and contents on my website and giveaways

Comment: Did you tried something? if so, please [edit] your question. interesting objective you want achieve. I really don't know if google API exposes any data that can be used along with YouTube Data API.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave No i haven't tried anything as of now, i am in the design and planning stage of my application. I want to architect my project and data flow in a  linear way. Hence i like to know all the information i can before i get started.

Comment: not to be rude here or anything, but questions without showing any code *(or any attempt for complete the task you're working on)* tend to be ignored by the community. My advice is: try search and read the documentation of both APIs.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave i understand that, i have read all the google api's for youtube + youtube live streaming and wasn't able to find a solution hence i asked here